# Kubernetes Node Status While it is being created

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes, fabric8-kubernetes-client

Getting the Kubernetes nodes information.

```cs
var client = MinikubeTests.CreateClient();
var node = client.CoreV1.ListNode().Items.First();
var nodeName = node.Metadata.Name;
```

Getting the node conditions as:

```cs
foreach(var nodeStatus in node.Status.Conditions) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", nodeStatus.Type, nodeStatus.Status);
}
```

[image]

Here the node ready status is true. How can we get the status while the node is being created?

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried to "watch" rather than doing a single "list node" request? Otherwise, clarify what you are asking about.

Comment: @Jonas: I am not sure what watch is. I have tried looping through the nodes but still the same

Comment: I want to get detail status of the node like for example, creating, Ready, not ready, SchedulingDisabled or Unknown, etc. I want to list the nodes when they are initially being created.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I see what your getting at . Use `NodeCondition`. It  provides information about various conditions or states of a `node`, such as whether it is ready or not . `NodeCondition` may not immediately indicate the readiness status as True because it takes some time for the node to become fully operational.

Firstly check if the `creating` condition is present and supported by your cluster at all .  presence of a `Creating` condition in the node status may depend on the version and configuration of your `Kubernetes cluster`. This condition is not a standard condition type and may not be present in all clusters. If your `cluster` does not include this condition, you can use the `Ready` condition to determine if the node is ready or not and to that extent you will loose granularity .

check if the `Creating` condition is present in the node status by retrieving the node information and checking the `Conditions` property of the node’s status.

```
var client = MinikubeTests.CreateClient();
var node = client.CoreV1.ListNode().Items.First();
var nodeName = node.Metadata.Name;

// Check if the node has a Creating condition
var creatingCondition = node.Status.Conditions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Creating");
if (creatingCondition != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Node has a Creating condition.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Node does not have a Creating condition.");
}
```

If this condition is present, it means that the node has a `Creating` condition. Otherwise, it means that the node does not have this condition.
That's regardless of whether the node is ready or not. It does this by retrieving the node information and checking the `Conditions property` of the node’s status to see if it includes a condition with Type set to `"Creating"`.

If the `creating` condition is present then run the below code to catch if the node is  in that condition  Again This condition may not be present in all `Kubernetes clusters,` as it is not a standard condition type. If your cluster does not include this condition, you can use the `Ready` condition to determine if the node is ready or not.

```
var client = MinikubeTests.CreateClient();
var node = client.CoreV1.ListNode().Items.First();
var nodeName = node.Metadata.Name;

// Check if the node is in the process of being created
var creatingCondition = node.Status.Conditions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Creating");
if (creatingCondition != null && creatingCondition.Status == "True")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Node is still being created.");
}
else
{
    // The node is not being created, check if it is ready
    var readyCondition = node.Status.Conditions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Ready");
    if (readyCondition != null && readyCondition.Status == "True")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Node is ready.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Node is not ready.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but my issue is that node.Status.Conditions is not displaying the status while the node is being created. It is providing the status as True and Type as Ready.

Comment: see  modified answer

Comment: still same issue, it is not detecting node status type "Creating"

Comment: check if the creating condition is present and supported by your cluster at all  - read the modified answer.  and respond on above